# error while building custom dataloaders fastai

Tags: autoencoder, fast-ai

I'm trying to reproduce
https://walkwithfastai.com/tab.ae

but I got erorr: error: Module fastai.tabular.all notfound
I solved it by upgrading, then I got another error while building dataloader
IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got [None]

at first I was using versions:
fastai: 1.0.61
fastcore: 1.0.16
which gave me the error: Module fastai.tabular.all notfound

I upgraded to the latest version
fastai: 2.7.12
fastcore: 1.5.29

This solves the issue and produced another one.

it seems like a comptability issue.

I followed the doc to install https://docs.fast.ai/

but the issue persisted.